# Server not able to reply back to client in perl

Tags: perl, sockets

I am using Perl to implement client-server commmunication via socket programming.

I am sending some data from client to server, but I am not able to see anything on the server unless the client is killed using Ctrl-C.

Also, whatever is returned from the server never reaches the client.

This is the first time I have tried to do client-server programming and I have no clue what to do.

I am using the [`IO::Socket::INET`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::INET) module.

Here is my code

**server**

```
use IO::Socket::INET;

my ($socket, $client_socket);
my ($peeraddress, $peerport);

$| = 1;

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
  LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
  LocalPort => '5000',
  Proto     => 'tcp',
  Listen    => 5,
  Reuse     => 1
) or die "Error in socket creation: $!\n";

while (1) {
  $client_socket = $socket->accept();
  $data = <$client_socket>;
  print "Received from socket is $data\n";
  print "Sending to socket\n";
  $client_socket->send("hello");
}

$socket->close();
```

**client**

```
use IO::Socket::INET;

$| = 1;

my($socket,$client_socket);

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
  PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
  PeerPort => '5000',
  Proto => 'tcp',
) or die "Error in socket creation : $!\n";

print $socket "mailshow 018DB3FCE4";
$socket->recv($data,1024);
print $data;
sleep(5);
$socket->close();
```

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` and declare your variables with `my` at their first point of use. You should also avoid *indirect object notation*, so `new IO::Socket::INET(...)` should be `IO::Socket::INET->new(...)`. The [*Invoking Class Methods* section of `perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Invoking-Class-Methods) says *“We recommend that you avoid this syntax, for several reasons”*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to hazard a guess that it's this:

```
$data = <$client_socket>;
$client_socket->send("hello");

print $socket "mailshow 018DB3FCE4";
$socket->recv($data,1024);
```

When you're reading from `$client_socket` as a file handle, it's trying to read a *line* of data. This line of data is defined by `$/` and is by default a line feed (or end-of-file). You don't send a line feed, so that `$data= <$client_socket>` blocks until you terminate the process.

I would guess that if you:

- `undef $/`
- send `\n`
- or use `send`/`recv` exclusively

You won't have this problem.

Refer to [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Internet-TCP-Clients-and-Servers) for an example. And please, please please - turn on `strict` and `warnings`. It's only polite when asking for assistance.

This seems to do what you want:

### Client:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;
$| = 1;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort => '5000',
    Proto    => 'tcp',
) or die "Error in socket creation : $!\n";

print {$socket} "mailshow 018DB3FCE4\n";
my $data;
$socket->recv( $data, 1024 );
print "Client received: ",$data,"\n";
sleep(5);
$socket->close();
```

### Server:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;

$| = 1;
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => '5000',
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    Listen    => 5,
    Reuse     => 1
) or die "Error in socket creation: $!\n";

while (1) {
    my $client_socket = $socket->accept();
    my $data          = <$client_socket>;
    print "Received from socket is $data\n";
    print "Sending to socket\n";
    $client_socket->send("hello");

}

$socket->close();
```

Although as a style point - I'd strongly recommend *against* mixing `print`/`<>` and `send`/`recv` in your code - it's a great way to lead to confusion down the line.

e.g.:

```
print {$socket} "mailshow 018DB3FCE4\n";
my $data = <$socket>;
print "Client received: ",$data,"\n";
```

And:

```
my $data          = <$client_socket>;
print "Received from socket is $data\n";
print "Sending to socket\n";
print {$client_socket} "hello\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I will take your comments on good practices and will follow them. Also using send/recv only solve my problems Thanks again

Comment: `$| = 1` will set autoflush on the current output — here that is `STDOUT`. It is best to say what you mean with `STDOUT->autoflush` and `$socket->autoflush`. That requires `IO::Handle`, which has been loaded automatically on demand (via `IO::File` and `IO::Seekable`) since v5.14

Comment: I have used `$|=1` and i am reading like this `socket->read($data,1024);` on client. The issue is that i am not able to get last few bytes on `STDOUT`  which i think is due to the fact that i am reading it into `1024 byte` buffer and since buffer is not full client waits. But i have nothing more to send from server side so how to get those last few bytes.